# How to search for all occurrences of the string `**` in a file using vim?

Tags: vim, neovim

How to search for `**` in a file using vim like `**kwargs` , when I use a `/**` it highlights the entire file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` is a meta-character that needs to be escaped to become a regular character:

```
/\*\*
```

Vim refers to this as "magic": if the pattern is "magic", you need to escape meta-characters, if it is "nomagic", you don't (this is a bit over-simplified, see `:help magic`).

Therefore, you can force Vim to treat the pattern as "nomagic" with `\M` or even "very nomagic", with `\V`:

```
/\V**
```

Which doesn't help much, here, but well…

As for why `/**` highlights the whole buffer, a hint can be found under `:help /star`:

```
Exception: When "*" is used at the start of the pattern or just after
"^" it matches the star character.
```

- The first `*` matches (at least some of) the stars in your buffer,
- The second `*` matches zero or more of the preceding atom, as many as possible, so, essentially, every character.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the * symbol, try

> /\*\*

On the text below I added extra spaces to be easier to read

> #Don't use this one 
> / \* \*